# Why would analysts recommend buying companies with negative net income?

Tags: stock-analysis, stock-valuation, yahoo-finance

Can anyone explain why some analysts recommend companies in the biopharmacy sector as a "buy" even though they have high R&D costs and no real profit?

I followed three companies and I see the same story. The only positive number is income, and only in one case does it cover expenses after net borrowing. For the next four in a row, the net income the net income is below zero.

Why are these companies a buy?

Comment: Well this is the link: http://biz.yahoo.com/ic/515.html
Where the first two symbols is easy to navigate and see the numbers. Ziopharm and Oragenics grabed my interest.

Comment: I wouldn't take an analyst's opinion, look at the charts - a picture says 1000 words.

Comment: Victor I agree off course, well... even though I agree, that does not answer the "why". What amazes me is that seeking in internet, I find relevant sites of finance calculators where say the same: "strong buy". I don't get it.
The companies' revenue is below zero for good.

Comment: I had a quick look at them and did not see any strong buy recommendations. To understand an analyst's recommendations you have to figure out the basis of their recommendation - is it based on current performance or future potential performance based on certain assumptions???

Comment: Exactly.I do not find any clue. I don't know.

Comment: If you don't understand the recommendation you should stay away from it. Too many people blindly follow other peoples recommendations and then complain when they get burnt.

Comment: victor, off course. \The question is, if someone can explain why the analysts say that is "strong buy'. WHo ever is that "analyst" group. If someone can understand what is not obvious to me. Becaues what I see is full of negative incomed balance sheets, and in one of the statements I read some very discouraging comments. But "analysts" say "strong buy". Do I miss something?

Comment: I don't know where you get strong buy recommendation from, I just went into a couple of these companies from the link you provided and there is no strong buy recommendation for them. For example the last recommendation for ZIOP was on Oct 15, 2012 - "Market Perform".

Comment: Yes the recomendations are not recent-recent, but it's ain't 10 years back. Here is an example: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ao?s=OGEN+Analyst+Opinion
1.0=Strong buy. If date is Oct15 2012, as you mention, that is ok. It's previous October. Quite close enough as time. And if you see the fundamentals around this age, nothing spectacular as well. And going to the present, it just boldifies the opposite view. "Strong sail" that is. Right?

Comment: This recommendation is from one analyst and it is Buy not Strong Buy, it is 6 months old and I would not be relying on it to assess the performance of the stock. Like I said I have no interest in what recommendations analyst's make as I make my own decisions, that way I only have myself to blame is things don't go the way I think they should (but that is a different story).

Comment: The first group shown in the page you linked was for the top movers of the past week. These aren't recommendations, just the highest percent change in price.

Comment: @hephestos I edited your question to make it a bit more clear, since I think this is an important question because it raises the general issue in fundamental analysis of why analysts would recommend stock(s) that at first glance, doesn't seem to make any profit.

Comment: @Editors, thank you for the corrections.I am not native speaker. Forgive me for any mistakes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The biotechnology sector as a whole is a popular buy recommendation among some analysts these days for a few reasons.

1. Some analysts feel that the high costs in R&D, even without much profit, are a positive sign for growth because it means a company is working towards finding the next "blockbuster drug" or the next class of such drugs. There haven't been many new classes of blockbuster drugs since the development of [SSRI's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSRI) and [statins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statins), and many of the new drugs that *have* been developed have been tweaks to existing classes of drugs. Some analysts feel that "it's about time" for a new class of blockbuster drugs to hit the market. A new blockbuster drug means significant profits for the company that develops it; a new *class* of blockbuster drugs means significant profits for the whole industry.
2. Since about 2009, the Food and Drug Administration has been more lenient in its approval of new drugs. This wave of new approvals has reduced R&D costs for companies because they don't need to go back to the lab or earlier phases of clinical trials and continually tweak their drugs in order to gain approval. This has also made some analysts optimistic.
3. Genetic engineering is considered an up-and-coming field with potentially significant applications to the pharmaceutical industry. Advances in this field may increase profits for the pharm industry, but since biotech companies are often the ones *producing* the engineering equipment, research, etc. such advances could be a major source of revenue for the entire biotech industry.
4. In the US and in the developed world as a whole, the elderly population is growing, and since people consume more medicine as they grow older, this could lead to higher profits for companies involved in the production of pharmaceuticals (which includes biotech companies, of course) in the long run.
5. In the US, the passage of the [Patient Protection and Affordable Care Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordable_Care_Act) expanded insurance coverage, which gives more people the means to afford pharmaceuticals. Also, in general, people consume more healthcare services when they have insurance (this is called [moral hazard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_hazard)), so some analysts expect that the expansion of insurance coverage will only lead to more profits for the pharmaceutical industry and biotechnology firms in general.
6. The global food crisis. As the climate changes, companies like Monsanto, which use various forms of genetic engineering to produce crop strains that can survive in increasingly hostile environments, look more and more appealing to places that need crops designed to grow in such environments. *Any* methods that could increase yields look increasingly popular, and biotechnology companies often market such methods. (As a side note, I know Monsanto is a contentious example, and there are *a lot* of misconceptions about "genetically modified food" and the genetic engineering methods they do, so I won't get into a debate about that).
7. In general, technology is a popular subject right now. I've read analyst reports (from analysts that clearly don't follow the biotech sector) that base their forecasts for the biotech sector on the activities of companies like Dell, Zynga, HP, LinkedIn, Facebook, etc. Clearly, it's problematic when an analyst sees the word "technology" and automatically assumes that the biotech sector is responsive to the same factors as social media firms, hardware manufacturers, etc. This isn't to say that the biotech sector is completely isolated from this, but when I read a report that talks about Facebook's IPO being bad news for companies like Gilead Sciences *without mentioning upcoming FDA decisions about Gilead's products* or any biotech-specific factors, I'm not convinced the analyst has performed due diligence.

I keep using the phrase "some analysts" because I want to stress that the opinions stated above aren't universal. Although they're popular, not everyone is so optimistic. **Also, I don't want you to see these reasons and think that I'm making a buy recommendation, because I'm not.** I'm not making a recommendation one way or another.

I'm happy to clarify my answer too; I follow the biotechnology sector extensively. If you want to get a rough feel for the daily movements of the sector as a whole, a good place to start is [IBB](http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/IBB%3aUS), the iShares Nasdaq Biotechnology Index Fund. The four largest holdings are Regeneron, Gilead Sciences, Amgen, and Celgene, which are all big players in the industry (obviously). These are a little different from the big name pharma companies like Pfizer, Merck, Novartis, etc. but they're still considered pharma companies.

It's also worthwhile to follow the [FDA press announcements](http://www.fda.gov/NewsEvents/Newsroom/PressAnnouncements/default.htm). By the time the news is published there, it's probably already leaked or known to people in the industry (the biotech/pharm sectors are rife with accusations of insider trading), so you might not find trading opportunities, but it's important to get familiar with the information the releases contain if you want to know more about the industry. Volatility trades are always popular trades around FDA drug approvals.

Comment: John, thank you for your interest. It is very informative anwer. Thank you for the links.

Comment: off course it seems to be the best answer. I just wanted to give more time. In any case many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Companies in their earliest stages will likely not have profits but do have the potential for profits.  Thus, there can be those that choose to invest in companies that require capital to stay in business that have the potential to make money.

[Venture Capital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venture_capital) would be the concept here that goes along with John Bensin's points that would be useful background material.  For years, Amazon.com lost money particularly for its first 6 years though it has survived and taken off at times.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely because they don't know what they're talking about.

They all have a belief without evidence that information set X is internalised into the price but information set Y is not. If there is some stock characteristic, call it y, that belongs to set Y, then that moves the gauge towards a "buy" recommendation.

However, the issue is that no evidence has been used to determine the constituents of X and Y, or even whether Y exists in any non-trivial sense.